# AS - Translation Editor - How to delete string in all languages at once?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2, translation-editor

I have few strings that translated to 4 languages, but interface changed, and now I'm wondering, if there are any possibility to delete string in all languages at once? (I'm using Android Studio 2.2)

Now it's not a big problem now, but when there are will be more than 4 languages it could be difficult. Maybe I should create feature request for Android Studio about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio 2.3 I've found a little button, but it searches for usages before deletion and it takes really long time.

In the translation editor select a string key and then press little "-" button at top left. Screenshot attached.

[image: screenshot]